# I am looking for a word in English that means something specific about the immediate present

Tags: single-word-requests, time, present-tense

I'm doing research on manufacturing systems and throughout my papers I need to refer to events as they approach a line t=0 which is, to within a differential slice of time, the exact present between future and past, the dissecting line. Such a word would have quantum physicists turn in their graves due to relativity I know, but I think what it means is clear enough for English.

I've read that *origo* may mean what I want. It seems strange that such a word doesn't exist, and I've searched for weeks. I know the word 'now' sort of means that but it's ambiguous and still represents a spacious present.

Some members suggest I add the following to the question:

**My current definition of the word as it is in the paper:**

> A concept that will be used to discuss aspects of this paper needs to
>   be defined. There exists a bisecting line between future and past, the
>   immediate present line. This line has no width and, not considering
>   the effects of relativity, is the instant in time in which all matter,
>   process states, and information exists in the instant between “about
>   to” and “was just”. The problem with the word “now”, apart from it
>   being an adverb and not a noun, is that it still represents a spacious
>   present and not the rigorous bisector between future and past. This
>   bisector will be called the origo, from the pragmatic sense of the
>   word. Origo means the point of departure of a perspective on a
>   subject. Since anything in existence always has the time-based point
>   of departure from the immediate present into the future or into the
>   past, the origo is the universally experienced immediate
>   present when the subject of time is considered

**A sentence in the paper where I use it:**

> Looking at humans and other organic systems and how this problem of
>   flexible activity execution is performed, it’s noticed that the
>   execution plan only crystallises around the origo, where actions
>   further ahead of the origo remain less defined and ambiguous.

**Another Sample**

> An activity can be broken into a series of actions which themselves
>   can be broken into smaller sub-actions which leads to a philosophical
>   problem like Zeno’s paradox where this sub-dividing defines actions
>   down to the movement of individual molecules. Since engineering is
>   about practical problem solving and not about the conundrums of
>   philosophy, some decision needs to be made about where the
>   cut-off point should be. The addition of the spacious present (stage 2) 
>   Execution Phase as part of an activity life cycle solves this problem.
>   While individual actions can sequentially cross the origo to the past, an 
>   entire activity is not completed until its final action is.

The value of the paper is not dependent on using the correct word, but it bugs me that either I'm missing something huge, or the word doesn't exist.

Thanks for the help so far guys.

Comment: The only word i can think of is the "Origin" in a Cartesian Coordinate System

Comment: *Origin* sounds strange to me, but I'm not used to thinking of it in terms of mathematics. I'm not sure if you need something specific to that domain or not. What do you mean when you say that *now* is ambiguous and you mention a "spacious present"? As far as I know, *now* is very precise. The only problem with it is our inability to grasp it intuitively—because as soon as it is *now*, it no longer is. (But I'm not sure if that's what you're talking about or if our inability to fully intuit it invalidates the word. Any word or label would have the same issue.)

Comment: @Chappo "t=0" is a common enough concept.

Comment: @Kris t=0 represents a single point in a time series. The OP is asking for something far more nuanced: an expression for t=0 within a time function that is constantly resetting.

Comment: @Chappo See my answer.

Comment: @JasonBassford You said exactly what the problem is. Normal language is used to walking along time as it moves, not trying to stop it right before 'now' becomes a fraction of the past. But I need to describe things philosophically with mathematical precision.

Comment: @Kris, I used t=0 in many diagrams, but it does not flow well in a sentence. I've settled for defining the word at the start of the paper. I don't like its sound, origo, but If you guys have better suggestions then I'll gladly replace it.

Comment: Yes, I understand you need a name for t=0. However, disappointing it may be though, *origo* is not the word, as it is synonymous with *origin* -- which is necessarily in the past.

Comment: @Kris, I understand that the origin of origo is origin, but in pragmatics it does not mean it's in the past, but only seen as where the point of view originates from. So my reasoning is that since "now" is the point of view for anything in existence looking into the future or the past, "origo" is the universal term for that point in time.

Comment: Not just etymology, its usage is also on the same lines, as one should expect.

Comment: @Kris, if you had to make up a word for this concept, what would the etymology be? Maybe I can start from there.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could provide a sample sentence where you would use this word. In fact, I suggest that you 1. cut and paste (into your question, above) the paragraph where you (in the present version of your text) define the word *origo*, and then 2. cut and paste the first sentence in the text where you actually use that word in its intended sense.

Comment: Thank you, the definition and examples you posted are very helpful. I will think a bit more about your question now. Meanwhile, I just want to mention that *origo* is also a name for a concept used in linguistics, in the context of [deixis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deixis). There it is also called the *deictic center* (see [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=CLJqDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PT66&dq=%22origo%20also%20known%20as%20deictic%20center%22&pg=PT66#v=onepage&q=%22origo%20also%20known%20as%20deictic%20center%22&f=false)).

Comment: In that context one needs to distinguish temporal, spatial, and person origos (see e.g. [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=7WJCAAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA35&dq=temporal%2C%20spatial%2C%20and%20person%20origos&pg=PA35#v=onepage&q=temporal,%20spatial,%20and%20person%20origos&f=false)). You can find many more references by doing [this search](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=deictic+origo) on google books.

Comment: Another comment: *now* is also a noun, see e.g. [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/now) (you'll need to scroll down), with the meaning 'the present time or moment'. Thus one way to describe what you want is *the instantaneous now.* I'm not saying that's better than *origo,* but it could be used in the passage in which you are explaining what *origo* means. (I'm not done thinking about your question, though.)

Comment: @linguisticturn Thanks for your help. It's from that pragmatic use of the word where I got the idea from. I'm going to look through those papers you linked.

Comment: @linguisticturn That book link about the deixis confirms why I used origo in the first place. I think it's the best option so far but if you find a word in another language that sounds more elegant then I'll consider it.

Answer (score 1):

[current](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/current)

> **1** Belonging to the present time; happening or being used or done now.

A typical sentence might look like:

> The equation is based on the **current** instantaneous value of the parameter (as at the time of measurement).

Comment: Your word “current” is redundant given the words “instantaneous” and “as at the time of measurement”, and without these qualifications it is as imprecise as “present”.  Perhaps *instantaneous* on its own might be the word the OP is looking for?

Comment: @Chappo *Current* and *instantaneous* are independent and refer to different things. No confusion.

Comment: @Chappo *Current* without *instantaneous* could belong to timeslice (t-n to t+n) where t=0; it doesn't necessarily mean **at t=0**.

Comment: Yes, current would need to be added to instantaneous since I'm talking about a specific point in time, the 'now' point. I want to try avoid long two word terms since I need to draw many diagrams and keep long sentences simple.  I spoke to a linguistics friend of mine and she said I could use origo as long as I just define what it means.

Comment: As long as I just define what it means, you could use any **made-up** word or symbol, not an existing one with a defined meaning.

Comment: See also: https://books.google.co.in/books?id=78TgCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA208&lpg=PA208&dq="current+instant"  ; https://books.google.co.in/books?id=BkjTPruWMScC&pg=PA349&lpg=PA349&dq="current+instant" HTH.

Answer (score 1):

In common everyday life there's been little need for an expression of the immediate (and constantly becoming *past*) instant of now, given that the moment it's expressed, that time-point has already ceased to be "now": it's become "just a moment ago" . The word that comes closest to expressing this concept is:

### instantaneous

> 1. done, occurring, or acting without any perceptible duration of time
>
>    - death was *instantaneous*
> 2. done without any delay being purposely introduced
>
>    - took *instantaneous* corrective action
> 3. occurring or present at a particular instant
>
>    - *instantaneous* velocity
>
> [[Merriam-Webster Dictionary]](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/instantaneous)

While I think all three definitions have relevance, the third definition would appear to be the most apt. An alternative source provides a similar definition:

> 2. [*Physics*]
>      Existing or measured at a particular instant.
>
>    - *‘measurement of the instantaneous velocity’*
>
> [[Oxford Living Dictionaries]](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/instantaneous)

Example sentence in the context of this question:

> *This metric analyses the instantaneous value of the parameter.*

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is graph something fixed that cannot remain fixed and is true only until you express it—at which point it becomes false.

Although it isn't a single word, and its explanation is a lot more nuanced than just what you're looking for, Zen Buddhism uses the term **eternal now** to express something close to what you're looking for.

From Brian Thompson's ["The Eternal Now"](http://www.zenthinking.net/blog/the-eternal-now) at Zen Thinking:

> Time is a concept of human mind, that can exist only within mind. Outside of mind and its multiplicity of concepts and theories, there is only the ever-present, continuous, and uninterrupted Now. Therefore, anything outside of the here and now is non-existent. The past is merely an appearance that exists within the human function of memory. It has no present reality.

That description also makes use of the term **ever-present**.

Note that in both cases an adjective needs to be added to the normally single word in order to more properly convey the sense sought. By adding *eternal* to *now* or *ever-* to *present* it forces us to think of something that fixed in our consciousness even though it is seemingly moving.

So, from the perspective of the eternal now, which always *is* (at any particular time), there is a perceived past and a perceived future.

---

Note: in the hope of getting you a single word out of this, I thought I'd look up the Japanese equivalent. Unfortunately, it seems to be expressed in three Japanese words. From [*Perversion and Modern Japan*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=CvZ8AgAAQBAJ&pg=PA88&lpg=PA88&dq=the%20eternal%20now%20japanese&source=bl&ots=CbvrPxG9W3&sig=MpbszdgFveihyC68415u_kStH0k&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjVnIuNgfLeAhVQhuAKHcZNBY84ChDoATAFegQICBAB#v=onepage&q=the%20eternal%20now%20japanese&f=false), edited by Nina Cornyetz and J. Keith  Vincent:

> Thus, the "woman" is the "Japanese 'eternal now'" (*ein no ima*)—or more accurately, the "eternity of the present" (*ima no eien*) which dominates the "ancient substratum" of historical consciousness with the "drive to go onwards."

Perhaps you can find some single word in a different language that expresses this—if any of them are able to express it in a single word, unlike what seems to be the case in English (or Japanese).

Alternatively, you could make use of this two-word phrase in the definition of the single word that you'll use in the remainder of your essay. Or you could opt to simply capitalize or represent *[Now]* in a different visual way when using it in this particular sense.

Answer (score -1):

What about word **beginning**. Or you could add your own explanation/definition in the introduction part of your paper. For example: throughout this paper, I will refer to /*your definition*/ as **initiation point/origo/origin/or something**. Then you can always add note*(asterisk) with reference to definition, whenever this word appears in the text.

Comment: I agree with you saying I should define it. I spoke to a linguist friend of mine who said the same thing.